# Send lists and dictionaries in Python requests GET

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I built a test FastAPI instance with a `GET` operation as follows:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import List, Dict

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/result/")
async def root(d: Dict, l: List):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        d[keys[i]] = d[keys[i]] + l[i]
    return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

After running the API, I would like to try to launch a request via `requests.get()` with the parameters `d = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}` and `l = [3, 5, 8]`, I would like to understand how to write the url in `r = requests.get(...)`.

Comment: request.get("<host>:<port>/<url>"), in get request you dont pass the parameters

Comment: You can't really do that with a GET request. You'd have to use a POST request with a JSON body. `requests.post('...', json={'d': {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}}`

Answer (score 0):

A clean way is to build a *model* for your expected inputs, as in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/

And you have to use *post* instead of *get*.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30877239)